# Creating interactive map with processing

Tags: processing, interactive, world-map

We are trying to find a way to create interactive maps with Processing, in which we can:

1. Hover over countries with mouse and have the whole country be highlighted.
2. Have the user click on the country and provide additional information on that country.

These would entail that there is a package in Processing with the areas of each country defined. Does such a package exist? I know they exist for the jQuery space through [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/). Does the equivalent exists for Processing?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following sources:

- http://mapbox.com/tilemill/
- http://unfoldingmaps.org/